# Select multiple records with multiple selectors but also limit 1?

Tags: mysql

I have to return multiple records based on a not-unique selector.
The table to select from is page_objects and there are multiple objects per page (parent table).

I have an array with multiple page_ids and I want to return the last edited page_object of each page_id.

The query without the SELECT IN:

```
SELECT `object` FROM `page_objects` WHERE `f_page_id` = $iPage_id ORDER BY last_change DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I want to get something like this:

```
SELECT `object` 
FROM `page_objects`
WHERE `f_page_id` IN ($iPage_id1,$iPage_id2,...) ORDER BY last_change DESC  LIMIT 1;
```

Can I create a single query for this?

### EDIT

I notice that my question is not really clear.
I want to return a page_object per given page_id.
Example:

```
SELECT `f_page_id`, `page_object_id`, `object` 
FROM `page_objects`
WHERE `f_page_id` IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY last_change DESC  LIMIT 1;
```

Should return:

```
page_id    page_object_id    object
1          1                 ...
2          7                 ...
3          45                ...
```

Other page_objects that match the page_ids given should be limited to just one!
So page_object_id 2, which is also a page_object of page with id 1, should not be returned, because it's not edited last.

Comment: Your query looks OK to me.  Have you tried it?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to `GROUP BY` your query:

```
SELECT `f_page_id`, `page_object_id`, `object` 
FROM `page_objects`
WHERE `f_page_id` IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY f_page_id
ORDER BY last_change DESC;
```

This way, all your objects are first sorted by last change and then grouped by page id, thus, it will return the last changed object per page.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!